# Dynamic graphs and DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, jpgraph

I'm using `DOMPDF` to create PDF (with `load_html()`, not `load_html_file()`). I need some graphs to be in the PDF, and I've been trying with `jpgraph`.

I can't figure out how to make this work. The graph has to be dynamically generated with PHP, and it cannot be saved on the server. I can easily get the graph outputted, but it won't get into the PDF, since `DOMPDF` can't load PHP as image.

Any suggestions? It doesn't have to be `jpgraph`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it works with full image urls now ("remote access"). So if anybody else has the same problem, enable remote in DOMPDF config, and you can use full URLs.

Comment: Great you have solved your issue, but next time you should show your code in a question. It's very hard to say why something doesn't work, if you can't see it. Check [StackOverflow's help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), please.

Comment: dompdf retrives external resources (images, stylesheets) using `file_get_contents()`. It expects these resources to be in their final form, so a dynamically-generated image has to be rendered before it gets to dompdf. There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is to just go through your web server (i.e. using a full URL).